# How to rename or relabel a Network Drive label

Tags: c++, windows, network-drive

I am mounting a network drive to windows using [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is working fine but while mounting the drive by default it assigns the name as Server IP and FolderName ,

> NDSTestFolder on 'NAS server (172.24.17.116)'(R:)

I need to rename the drive label using [SetVolumeLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365560%28VS.85%29.aspx)  but this fails for the network drive saying invalid parameter while **SetVolumeLabel**  works fine for the local drives.

Is there a way I can rename or relabel a network drive? So that I can change

> NDSTestFolder on 'NAS server (172.24.17.116)'(R:)

to

> NDS@MyFolder (R:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translated your script into C++:

```
#include <shldisp.h>

void RenameDrive(BSTR strNewName, BSTR strDriveLetter)
{
   IShellDispatch* pShellDispatch = NULL;

   HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell,
                                 NULL,
                                 CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                 IID_IShellDispatch,
                                 (void**)&pShellDispatch);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pShellDispatch)
   {
      Folder* pFolder = NULL;
      VARIANT vt = {};
      VariantInit(&vt);
      vt.vt = VT_BSTR;
      vt.bstrVal = strDriveLetter;
      hr = pShellDispatch->NameSpace(vt, &pFolder);
      VariantClear(&vt);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pFolder)
      {
         Folder2* pFolder2 = NULL;
         hr = pFolder->QueryInterface(IID_Folder2, (void**)&pFolder2);
         if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pFolder2)
         {
            FolderItem* pFolderItem = NULL;
            hr = pFolder2->get_Self(&pFolderItem);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pFolderItem)
            {
               pFolderItem->put_Name(strNewName);
               pFolderItem->Release();
            }
            pFolder2->Release();
         }

         pFolder->Release();
      }

      pShellDispatch->Release();
   }
}
```

Comment: Much better solution for a C++ application!

Comment: Thanks for provdin the solution in C++ , marked as answer and +1 too for that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's an API for this but the strings are stored in the registry under:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2

Find the correct subkey  by parsing the keys there (it will probably look like "##172.24.17.116#NDSTestFolder" ) and change the _LabelFromReg value to whatever you like...

Comment: Such registry entries have changed between XP and Vista, Vista and 7, and possibly between different service packs thereof. That's the price of undocumented interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using vb script for renaming thr drive:

```
LPCTSTR szCode = "Function RenameDrive(strNewName,strDriveLetter) \r\n\
                     Dim objShell \r\n\
                     Set objShell = CreateObject(\"Shell.Application\") \r\n\
                     'if objShell is Not Nothing Then \r\n\
                     objShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter).Self.Name = strNewName \r\n\
                     'End if \r\n\
                     End Function";
```