# Changing the label of a network drive

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-drive

I'm trying to write a program, that adds a network connection with `WNetAddConnection2()` and then renames the newly created network drive.
The only way I found to do it, is either with PowerShell, or manually editing the registry.

The PowerShell way might be ok for C++ application, but my application has to be in C.

The registry edit was the former way how I renamed the folder, but when my application is run as a system service, modifying `HKCU` is not trivial.
Even if I modify the registry, I have to modify it per user, which doesn't change the label for new users.

This is the batch script I used previously to change the label:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##computername#sharename" /v  "_LabelFromReg" /t REG_SZ /d "label" /f
```

For some reason calling `SetVolumeLabel()` doesn't work at all.

Is there any other way to do this? Or at least some recommended way to change the registry for all users?

Comment: The powershell is equally OK or not OK independently of the language (C or C++).

Comment: I didn't find a way to call a powershell script from C, only from C++.
Could you point me in the rigth direction please?

Comment: How do you call powershell from c++? It should be the same from C. BTW: I'm not sure if you can call powershell from a service.

Comment: I found the code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460390/how-to-rename-or-relabel-a-network-drive-label

Comment: OK, as COM is involved that's not quite easy to get it right in C, but what prevents you from compiling your C code with the C++ compiler. C++ is more or less a superset of C.

Comment: I'm not really in charge of saying what language will be used, so I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Ask the person who is in charge. There is no reason why you shouldn't use the C++ compiler. Most C code can be compiled with the C++ compiler.

Comment: Failing a C++ compiler, you can certainly use COM from C, it is just ugly. I can't help but wonder, though, why in the world you are mapping a network drive from a *service*. That just doesn't make sense. These drive mappings only make sense from within an interactive console session, which you are not guaranteed with a service. What is wrong with just using the UNC path? Essentially all Windows APIs support this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz C++ supports managed extensions whereas C doesn't. All the examples for hosting Powershell I've seen are from C#. Translating from C# to managed C++ is straightforward. However translating from a managed language to an unmanaged language is quite involved.

Comment: @Χpẘ: Except, those hosting interfaces are exposed as COM interfaces. Translating COM code from a managed language to an unmanaged language is tedious, but straight forward. Whether you transcribe this to C++ or C doesn't make the job any more challenging, only more tedious in case of C.

Comment: @CodyGray We have a guest VM service, that handles shared folder as a network drive. The way we used to do it was with a batch script, which is not really user friendly. I am trying to do this more user friendly, so that when enabling the shared folder, it automatically maps the drive.

Comment: @IInspectable I was responding to MichaelWalz comments about hosting PS from C vs C++ (first comment). Not about accessing COM from C vs C++

Comment: Hmm, okay. I can think of ways that could be problematic, but I suppose it works in a controlled environment. Different question, then: why run it as a service? Just launch it at startup when a user logs in.

Comment: @CodyGray Mostly it's because we have the same code base for Linux and Windows, and for some reason the guy that implemented the Windows part of the code chose service. I am lobying for a change to a classic application, so that it can have a tray icon, which would be even better for the user, but for now I just have to finish this.
Seems like I will keep it per user with the REG hack, which will work ok after the rewrite to a startup application.